# Mysql Like statement in javascript with array of objects?

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs

I am pretty confused with relative searching in javascript For example

```
let array = [{name:'ram'},{name:'kumar ra'},{name:'nani'}]
```

If i search **ra** then array should be like `[{name:'ram'},{name:'kumar ra'}]`Similar to mysql Like statement .But i don't know how to do it in javascript ..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: use `.filter` to get your results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays have a `filter` ([Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=control)) method which behaves very much like a `where` clause.
It takes a predicate and returns a new array containing the elements that satisfy that predicate.

```js
const array = [{
  name: 'ram'
}, {
  name: 'kumar ra'
}, {
  name: 'nani'
}];

const filtered = array.filter(e => e.name.match(/ra/));

console.log(filtered);
```

In the predicate itself, we use `String`'s `match` ([String.prototype.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)) method to test each name against a regular expression. This is conceptually similar to a `like` expression in SQL.

The `filter` method walks the array and calls the predicate on each element of it. I have named this element `e` in inside the predicate. When the `filter` method calls the predicate, it passes the current element as the first argument thus binding it to `e`.

Comment: First thanks for your answer But what is the correct way to pass the variable inside match ...

Comment: @Nane the filter method walks the array and calls the predicate on each element of it. I have named this element in inside the predicate. When the filter method calls the predicate, e refers to the current item.

Answer (score 0):

you can apply filter method on array elements to find items that their names contains 'ra'

```
let result=array.filter((item)=>{return item.name.contains('ra')})
```

Comment: **Uncaught TypeError: item.name.contains is not a function**

Comment: It worked for me with the sample you gave above, if not can you try `item.name.indexOf` instead of `item.name.contains`